# A javascript slider array issue

Tags: javascript, css

Having a slider with images implementation from array, cant figure out why images dont want to be shown up from array, tryed to make a path but it didnt work.I want this code to reflect this image every time a push the button: fpoimg.com/100x100.
Im trying to fix it only with clean javascript.
Here is a sandbox

```js
var slider = {
 slides: ['100x100', '100x100', '100x100', '100x100'],
  frame:0,
  set:function(image){
   path = path || 'http://fpoimg.com/';
   document.getElementById('scr').style.backgroundImage ="url ("+path+ image+")";
  },
  init:function() {
  this.set(this.slides[this.frame]);
  },
  left:function() {
  this.frame--;
  if(frame < 0) this.frame = this.slides.length - 1;
  this.set(this.slides[this.frame]);
  },
  right:function() {
  if(this.frame == this.slides.length) this.frame = 0;
  this.set(this.slides[this.frame]);
  }
};

window.onload = function() {
 slider.init();
  setInterval(function() {
   slider.right();
  },5000);
};
```

```css
.scr {
 margin:20px auto;
 width: 600px;
 height: 320px;
 margin-top:20px;
 background-color: white;
 background-size:cover;
}
button {
 position: absolute;
 top: 150px;
 width: 25px;
 height: 150px;
 font-size: 30px;
 text-align: center;
  background:none;
  border:none;
}
.left {
 left:25px;
}
.right {
 right:25px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button class="left" onclick="slider.left();"><</button>
  <div class="scr"></div>
  <button class="right" onclick="slider.right();">></button>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you've got `getElementById()` when you meant `getElementsByClassName()`

Answer (score 0):

On `Line 6` of your Javascript, you have used `getElementById('scr')`. You have no element with an Id or `scr`, you needed to use `getElementsByClassName('scr')`

Your new code:

```js
var slider = {
  slides: ['100x100', '100x100', '100x100', '100x100'],
  frame: 0,
  set: function(image) {
    path = path || 'http://fpoimg.com/';
    document.getElementsByClassName('scr').style.backgroundImage = "url (" + path + image + ")";
  },
  init: function() {
    this.set(this.slides[this.frame]);
  },
  left: function() {
    this.frame--;
    if (frame < 0) this.frame = this.slides.length - 1;
    this.set(this.slides[this.frame]);
  },
  right: function() {
    if (this.frame == this.slides.length) this.frame = 0;
    this.set(this.slides[this.frame]);
  }
};

window.onload = function() {
  slider.init();
  setInterval(function() {
    slider.right();
  }, 5000);
};
```

```css
.scr {
  margin: 20px auto;
  width: 600px;
  height: 320px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  background-size: cover;
}
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 150px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  background: none;
  border: none;
}
.left {
  left: 25px;
}
.right {
  right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <button class="left" onclick="slider.left();">
  </button>
  <div class="scr"></div>
  <button class="right" onclick="slider.right();"></button>
</body>
```

Comment: Yes, u right, but it shows nothing. I want this code to reflect this image every time a push the button: http://fpoimg.com/100x100